# Google data studio report: get pages ids

Tags: google-drive-api, looker-studio

Please clarify such case:
i have a file of Google Data Studio report with 5 pages saved on Google Drive.

i know where to get file id(to access the file via GDrive API).
i know where to get manually page id of the report.

does there any API for Google Data Studio or for Google Drive that allows getting information(metadata) about all pages(at least page id) that Google Data Studio report has?

does information(metadata) about available pages saved automatically inside the Google Data Studio report file? How to get it via Google Drive API?

Comment: Hi @ДмитроКостильов! I want to help you, but I don't understand the issue. Could you please carify the format of your Google Data Studio report? For example, do you mean a PDF report? I understand that you want to get the contents of one page of the report, am I correct?

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron, well excuse me  for english

I try to clarify:
google data studio report has 5 pages. i look into metadata for GDS report file via Drive API. But inside metadata there is no information about pages of report. I want to get via API ids for each page that report has

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron am i clear? i dont need content of report page, only id of page.
url of report is [datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/1TvN7fxNcmFJWUEuDWm356sMOHg0MAHsIc/page/89yL.] **"89yL"** is ID of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available right now for Community Connectors(Jun 2020). You cannot access the page metadata via API.

However, you can make a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=345845&template=1162971).